# Relative path in preloading images

Tags: javascript, css, image, preloading, image-preloader

This may be a dumb question, but I've a real confusion and want to get an opinion from somebody who knows this in-out.

Preloading images can be done either via JavaScript or CSS (to name two which I'm considering). I read the tutorials that if the browser finds the same image path again, it would render the cached image.

If I preload images like:

`<img src="../images/bg.jpg" alt="background" width="1" height="1" style='display:none' />`

and

`<img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="background" />`

Similar with javascript:

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

preload([
    '../img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/imageName.jpg' // case when using this script in a different hierarchical level)
]);
```

Will the second call result into rendering of the image from the cached version or it will not work because the image **path** specified is different (though ultimately it refers to the same file).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The browser will determine the full path to the file before checking its cache - you can test this out using the Web Inspector tools or Firebug.

Comment: Do you mean to say the browser always uses the full absolute path to check if the image is cached or not?

Comment: yes that's right :) There are various factors influencing whether the browser should load a cached item or fetch it directly (ETags, expires headers etc) so browser will determine the full, absolute path first before looking at these and choosing what to do.

Comment: I would like to read about this and understand the concept for sure - do you have a link where something like this would be documented?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is and old one but I get this one all the time from interns - so here goes...

Even though the onload function is in the JS file asking/telling the browser to look for the image; it is the browser looking for the image and is telling the JS that the image/s loaded.

So your image path in the JS should be the same as how you would enter it in the HTML.

PS: I noticed in your HTML the image folder is "/images" and in your JS the folder is "/img"